# How can I derive a function and then calculate its maximum in R

Tags: r, function, derivative, calculus, maximize

I've tried using the functions D() and deriv() to derive the function, but the output is an expression so I can't use the method optimize() to get the maximum of the derivative.

Comment: Study the examples in `help("deriv")`.

Answer (score 1):

Try using Deriv::Deriv() function instead.
It returns function, not expression.
For a simple example,

```
    f <- function(x) x^2
    Deriv(f)
```

result is

```
    function (x) 
    2 * x
```

Now you can optimize() that derivative